# Open ACS / Project Open log file size increases too much (huge log size)

Tags: size, logfile, project-open

How to reduce the Opject-Opens log file size. ]Project-Open[ is based on the openACS framework and produces huge amount of logs.

One Example is a deprecated warning which occures very often.

After a few day the log file size i several GB which is very annoying and makes an editor really slow, makes it tough to find important informatoin.

I did
`set debug false`
in `etc/config.tcl`

Edit:

Start `/usr/lib/aolserver4/bin/nsd -it /web/projop/etc/config.tcl -u projop -g projop`

File: `/web/projop/etc/config.tcl`

```
ns_log notice "nsd.tcl: starting to read config file..."

###################################################################### 
#
# Instance-specific settings 
# These default settings will only work in limited circumstances
# Two servers with default settings cannot run on the same host
#
###################################################################### 


# Wait until PostgreSQL has come up...
# Sleep 5 is apparently not enough in certain situations
exec sleep 15


#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Web server ports. Change to 80 and 443 for production use or
# use "Pound" as a reverse proxy.
# If setting httpport below 1024 then please read comments in file:
# /var/lib/aolserver/service0/packages/etc/daemontools/run
#
set httpport            8000
set httpsport           8443


# The hostname and address should be set to actual values.
# setting the address to 0.0.0.0 means aolserver listens on all interfaces

# set hostname          localhost
set hostname            [ns_info hostname]

# set address           127.0.0.1
set address             "0.0.0.0"

set server              "projop"
set servername          "Sybit and Peers"
set serverroot          "/web/${server}"


# Debug is turned on for demo servers. Please turn off for
# performance critical production installations.
set debug               false

# Which database do you want? postgres or oracle
# The name of the database is the same as the server by default.
set database            postgres
set db_name             $server


# Home directory of AOLserver
set homedir             /usr/lib/aolserver4
set bindir              ${homedir}/bin


# Hard limits for up- and downloads
set max_file_upload_mb  20
set max_file_upload_min 5



###################################################################### 
#
# End of instance-specific settings
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your log file is so large is that you are logging in debug mode. You need to change the following and restart AOLserver.

In the AOLserver config file, verify/add this

```
set debug false
```

In the **ns/server/${server}/module/nslog** section, make sure this line is there

```
ns_param   debug              $debug
```

And, also in the **ns_section ns/parameters** section, make sure this is set

```
ns_param   debug              $debug
```

Comment: Yes I did restart the AOL Server. And posted the configuration now. I removed the deprecated tags as said in another answer

Comment: Thorsten, I've updated my answer. Even though you have set debug false, you still may need to explicly set it in the nslog module settings

Comment: @ThorstenNiehues Do you need more help? If this or another answer was helpful to you and answered your question, please don't forget to accept that answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd put a line in the crontab to force AOLserver to rotate the log every two hours or so:

```
1 */2 * * *     /bin/killall -HUP nsd
```

Cheers,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

Most of the useless (and big) log-entries are openAOL Server log warnings about deprecated functions.

So the first step would be removing deprecated warnings as discussed in [How to remove deprecated warning in log-file of open-ACS, Project-Open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32117531/how-to-remove-deprecated-warning-in-log-file-of-open-acs-project-open)